# What is mint rate in ERC721A?

Tags: remix, erc-721, solidity-0.8.x, ethereum-classic, erc

What is mintRate here ?

```
contract Contract721A is ERC721A, Ownable {
      uint256 public mintRate = 0.001 ether; 
    
        function setMintRate(uint256 _mintRate) public onlyOwner {
            mintRate = _mintRate;
        }
    }
```

Reference :
https://etherscan.io/address/0xd4299e6df45a393dc3104d02bb92dcd984f0f40f#code#F1#L29

Answer (score 1):

`mintRate` is just the price(ETH value) of one NFT on the current ERC721A contract

Look the below code snippet
Users can't mint any NFT when they don't pay more than or equal to ETH value of `mintRate * quantity`

```
uint256 public mintRate = 0.0069 ether;

function mint(uint256 quantity) external payable {
   require(msg.value >= (mintRate * quantity), "Not enough ether sent");
   _safeMint(msg.sender, quantity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sunny Williams

Comment: You are welcome @GauravPant

Answer (score 0):

The value of `mintRate` is 0.001 ether, or 1000000000000000 wei. It can be changed by reassigning through `_mintRate`.

Comment: Thanks for replying . But I was searching for a definition . What exactly is mintRate ?

Comment: mintRate is the minting amount of your NFT (not including the gas). See: https://blockchain.oodles.io/dev-blog/nft-smart-contract-development/